# Re-launch test execution after closing app manually in Android Espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I was looking for a solution on re-launching the application while my app is minimized and closed (removed from background). Is there a way to verify whether activity is running or not while test is executing? If activity is finished then test suite should identify and re launch the activity from background.

I did tried with customizing ActivityTestRule and re-launching, but my problem is app is getting relaunched only after next test execution happens. Since I need to re-launch immediately as soon as its closed within same test.

Looking through other similar queries, I have tried below solution but it still doesn't meets my requirement.

```
package android.support.test.rule;

public class ControlledActivityTestRule<T extends Activity> extends ActivityTestRule<T> {

public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass) {
    super(activityClass, false);
}

public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode) {
    super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, true);
}

public ControlledActivityTestRule(Class<T> activityClass, boolean initialTouchMode, boolean launchActivity) {
    super(activityClass, initialTouchMode, launchActivity);
}

public void finish() {
    finishActivity();
}

public void relaunchActivity(int seconds) {
    finishActivity();
    sleep(seconds);
    launchActivity();
    sleep(seconds);
}

public void launchActivity() {
    launchActivity(getActivityIntent());
}

public void sleep(int seconds) {
    if (seconds > 0) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(seconds * 1000);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
}
```

And calling launchActivity() in my test method.